# how to make own shell command with arguments in emacs?

Tags: emacs

I want to make my own shell command where i have a variable filename in the command. The filename is passed in an interactive function. I don't know how to save the filename passed as an argument to a variable and further use it to append the whole command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ask for a file name (or any other type of value), use [`interactive`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).  `(interactive "fFile: ")` means to ask for an existing file (that's what `f` stands for), prompting with `File:`.

Then, to concatenate a number of strings, use the `concat` function.

So the function would look something like this:

```
(defun my-cat-file (filename)
  (interactive "fFile: ")
  (shell-command (concat "cat " filename)))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me.   Can you just suggest any command that automatically takes the present file when i press enter (just like % in .vimrc file. basically i want that interactive command should not invoke automatically when i dont pass any argument as filename while calling the function and automatically takes the present file.